# How do I let input dictate which class to use?

Tags: java, class, conditional-statements

Basically I want the program to take input A or L to instantiate different classes. I have the construct in place for taking in those variables and such, I just need to know how to actually create a condition or switch that will initialize a class given the input. Code is as follows:

```
public constructor(char choice){
    if(choice == 'A'){
        classa<String> baga = new classa<String>();
        classa<String> bagb= new classa<String>();
    }
    else if(choice== 'L'){
        classb<String>  baga = new classb<String>();
        classb<String> bagb = new classb<String>();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what you are saying is that you would like to use `vowels` and `contants` as parameters in the construction of another object? Are the two classes that you are using (array bag and list bag) somehow related to a common ancestor?

Comment: You are already doing, whatever you describe. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want these variables to have different types, and you still expect to get some use out of them, then they must have some common operations. Those operations can be factored into a `Bag` interface:

```
public ConsonantCounter(char bagImplementationClass){
    Bag vowels;
    Bag consonants;
    if (bagImplementationClass == 'A'){
        vowels = new ResizableArrayBag<String>();
        consonants = new ResizableArrayBag<String>();
    } else if (bagImplementationClass == 'L'){
        vowels = new LinkedListBag<String>();
        consonants = new LinkedListBag<String>();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Incidentally, a `char` is not really type-safe here; I would use an enumeration. Further, I don’t like the use of mutation, so perhaps I’d go for something more along these lines:

```
final Bag vowels = makeLetterBag(type);
final Bag consonants = makeLetterBag(type);

private static IBag makeLetterBag(BagType type) {
    switch (type) {
    case RESIZABLE:
        return new ResizableArrayBag<String>();
    case LINKED_LIST:
        return new LinkedListBag<String>();
    }
}
```